# What is the difference shown in the browser when selecting element using jQuery and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery and JavaScript to select elements. I'm wondering what is the difference between these elements?  e.g $(this), this and such. It's kind of confusing.

[image]

Comment: Hi, please refrain from post your code as an image, post is as a formatted text instead. [Here is why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15366635). You can check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) Stack Overflow editing help to guide you on how do you format your codes. Goodluck :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is a JavaScript pointer to the caller of the function, sometimes an HTMLElement. `this` is entirely based on the context in which a function is called, for example, if you create a function in the outermost context of a JS file like so and log `this`, `this` is a pointer to the window.

```
function test() {
  console.log(this); //<-- this = window
}
test();
```

But a callback from an event on an input will show `this` as being the input HTMLElement.

```
let input = document.querySelector("input");
input.addEventListener("change", function(){
  console.log(this); //<-- this = <input>
});
```

`$(this)` is a jQuery object constructed with a pointer to `this`. jQuery objects add a ton of additional functions and shorthand substitutes for standard JavaScript functions. Check the jQuery documentation for all of the different things jQuery can do. You can also construct jQuery objects with a selector, like `$("div")`, which will contain all `<div>` elements on the page.

The `r.fn.init [...]` is just how jQuery objects are printed to the console, versus a standard HTMLElement which is just printed as HTML, e.g. `<input type="text"/>`

Comment: To add to this I'd recommend having a look at the jQuery docs for the jQuery object: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/

Comment: But how do I modifiy the attribute in the jquery object element like in JvaScript?

Comment: `.attr(name, value)`